# fetch user name from installed social media app using React native

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native

I want to develop this type of application where user can install our application and my application will fetch all user's id of installed social media account on their phone

It can possible in react native ? and if it possible so how can i done this ?

I only want a user-Id or user name (not a password or other sensitive information)

Comment: if this is possible then it's a privacy and security breach

Comment: Why do you need user information without user concern?

Comment: because  i want to develop a  system which can get only user name from diffrent social media account like Facebook, Instagram, Youtube channel by just connecting with Bluetooth or any other medium